# How do you undeploy 'helloworld.go' from App Engine Quickstart, and instead point to a html in bucket?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to learn about hosting websites on GCP, and have just finished the App Engine Quickstart, which gave me a working appspot.com domain which runs off helloworld.go.

But now I want to try a pre-made html template (contains .html, .DS_STORE, and css/fonts/images/js folders) that I have tested to be working locally.

Following the "Hosting a Static Website" tutorial, I have uploaded the html template folder into my bucket "... .appspot.com", and enabled the entire bucket to be publicly viewable/readable. Then I disabled and re-enabled the App Engine session to try and get it to reset.

However, the URL still loads the default "Hello, world" plaintext used in the Quickstart.

I may have a pretty fundamental misunderstanding of how web hosting on App Engine works. Could someone please check if what I'm trying to do is reasonable, and if so, how do I actually do it?

EDIT: I have also had success deploying other code samples included with Quickstart, but still haven't figured out how to ignore those and deploy directly from bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have a static HTML page in your Google Cloud Storage bucket and you want that app your App Engine application points to that html page.

It is possible to do that, just taking the files from the bucket and then printing the content, but if you just want a static page, the best option could be the following:

1. Create a bucket and upload ONLY the static template in that bucket, please, don't upload sensitive information there.
2. click in the three dots at the right to edit the permissions of the bucket.
3. give the "Storage Object Viewer" role to the member "allUsers" 
   [image: permissions]
4. enter into your bucket and click into the the public link of your index.html
   [image: public link]

The link will be something like: https://storage.googleapis.com/< YOUR_BUCKET >/index.html

**EDIT**

As requested by the OP, the link `https://storage.googleapis.com/< YOUR_BUCKET >/index.html` it's really long and not too friendly, for that reason this is a small tutorial of how to attach a custom domain to your Google Cloud Storage bucket.

1. Create a domain, you can use [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/) or if you just want a free domain, you can use something like [Freenom](https://www.freenom.com) and get your domain for free.
2. Go to [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and follow the small tutorial, this is just to verify that your domain it is actually yours. It will ask you to upload a file into your domain. To do this it's as simple as

   2.1. pointing your domain to the external IP of a Compute Engine Instance
   that you own with apache installed and the file in there.

   2.2. You can use the pre-made Compute Engine instance with lamp in the
   [Marketplace](http://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/lamp).

   2.3. Just upload the file provided by Google in
   /var/www/html/ inside of your new instance.

   2.4. Once your verification is done, delete this Compute Engine instance to 
   not to waste money.

3.Create a bucket with the same name as your verified domain, that means, if your domain is "larrycai.tk", your bucket should be called "larrycai.tk". If the "2." was made correctly it will let you create that bucket, if not, it will show you an error message saying that you need to verify that you are the owner of that domain.

4.Go again to your domain provider (in my case, freenom) and in the DNS menu add this record:
[image: DNS record]

as you see, you need to add a CNAME record and the target will be `c.storage.googleapis.com`, if it ask you to set a name, just add your domain "larrycai.tk".

5.(Optional) If you want to redirect your bucket url to a main file (like index.html for example), just run this command:

```
gsutil web set -m index.html gs://[your_bucket]
```

Now, with all theses steps, you should be able to see your static web page in your own domain.

Comment: I tried this by creating a new project and running the app engine tute just enough to create an appspot bucket for me, without deploying anything. 

Then I added the static files into this bucket and adjusted permissions. Back at the Storage 'dashboard', it does say "Public".

But both the base url (bucketdeploytest.appspot.com) and the +/index.html (bucketdeploytest.appspot.com/index.html) return 404s.

Am I still missing something?

Comment: Here you can find your static HTML template: https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketdeploytest.appspot.com/index.html

Comment: Thank you! I have also tested this in my original project (where the helloworld.go was deployed), this URL also works and displays the HTML template. So that project is hosting 2 websites, 1 on appspot and another on storage.googleapis. Is this just the default way to view sites hosted in buckets? I would like to know if it could be made more accessible with a shorter url like xxx.appspot.com. Nickson seems to be on to something, hope he responds again.

Comment: @LarryCai I updated my message explaining how to attach a custom domain to a GCS bucket.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways in deploying a site using Google Cloud Platform. The "Hosting a Static Website" tutorial refers to hosting a static website using Cloud Storage only.

To host a static website using App Engine, you will need to edit the app.yaml file of your application and create request handlers that will point to your static website.

As you are using the go qwikstart tutorial, I'm going to assume that your directory looks something like this:

```
helloworld
|-- app.yaml
|-- helloworld.go
|-- helloword_test.go
```

1. Create a new folder within the helloworld directory, in this example, I'm calling it `www`
2. Move your static files to the folder you just created, in my case the `www` folder
3. In the app.yaml file, add the following, replacing `www` with your folder name:

   ```
   handlers:
   - url: /
     static_files: www/index.html
     upload: www/index.html

   - url: /(.*)
     static_files: www/\1
     upload: www/(.*)
   ```
4. Deploy your application using `gcloud app deploy`.

For more info, Google provided documentation on serving static content for:

- [Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/building-app/serving-static-files)
- [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website)
- [PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website)
- [Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files)
- [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/static-content)
- [.NET](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/serving-static-files)
- [Ruby](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/serving-static-files)

Comment: I think I'm having trouble with the runtime: and api: lines. The html template does not indicate, and I tried all of them in "runtime:" while deleting the "api:" line. I have also tried "env: flex" which I saw in some other troubleshooting threads. 

How can I easily check the runtime to use? Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely, and I'm getting errors for other reasons?

Comment: I assume you’re talking about the app.yaml file? The only thing you need to do is add the handlers that I specified and leave the rest of the app.yaml unchanged